# How to fit the textarea to the table cell

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I am showing a textarea in my input in a table. But I want to resize it so that it covers the entire table cell, till the borders.

Logic -

```
<textarea type="textarea" value="{{data.directRowNo}}" id = "abc"
></textarea></td>
```

The css  I use is -

```
  #abc{
width: 100%;
height: 443%;
box-sizing: border-box;
resize: vertical;
max-height: 500px;
}
```

Image -

[image]

There is a bifurcation line that shows up which I don't want.

Comment: Show HTML of the table

Comment: Give position relative to parent and make child absolute with 100% height

Comment: (Is there some voodoo in angular that actually creates a `textarea` element based on `<input type="textarea"` …?)

Comment: @ Abhishek Pandey. How to define that . Can you help ? Position relative to parent and child height 100% height

Comment: just add css to textarea i.e textarea{ resize: none }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is [this](http://dabblet.com/gist/2893830) what you're looking for?

**CSS**

```
table {
    width: 500px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

table td {
    background-color: red;
    border: 0;
    min-height: 20px;
}

textarea {
    border: none;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* <=iOS4, <= Android  2.3 */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; /* FF1+ */
    box-sizing: border-box; /* Chrome, IE8, Opera, Safari 5.1*/
}
```

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            cell
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <textarea></textarea>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            cell
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The above code will resize the `<textarea>` along with the cell and will stretch the `textarea` till the cell border.

Answer (score -2):

```css
 #abc{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    resize: vertical;
    max-height: 500px;
    resize:none;
    }
    table{
    border:solid 1px black;
    }
table th{
border:solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
   


    <table>
    <th style="border">Header</th>
    <tr>
    <td><input type="textarea" id = "abc"></td>
    <tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: `<tbody>` in `<tr>`?

Comment: @AbhishekPandey what's your answer?

Answer (score -2):

Try setting the padding of td to 0: https://jsfiddle.net/upb51sth/

```
td {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 0;
}
```